# Get number of objects in serializer where foreign key field is x

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

Suppose

```
class ABC(models.Models):
    ...
    id = models.SlugField(...)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    ...
```

Now i want something like

```json
   [{id: adfsdd, no_of_user_objects: 5}, {id: gdfvsdf, no_of_user_objects: 0}, {id: ergthf, no_of_user_objects: 2}]
```

How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model [method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#model-methods) for getting the number of users having the same slug id:

```
class ABC(models.Models):
    ...
    id = models.SlugField(...)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    ...

    @property # for using in serializer
    def no_of_user_objects(self):
        return ABC.objects.filter(id=self.id).count()
```

And in your serializer have a custom serializer for the queryset serializer:

```
class ABDSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
        model = ABC
        fields = ['id', 'no_of_user_objects']

# in your view
queryset = ABC.objects.distinct('id')
serializer = ABDSerializer(queryset, many=True)
print(serializer.data)
# get you    [{id: adfsdd, no_of_user_objects: 5}, {id: gdfvsdf, #no_of_user_objects: 0}, {id: ergthf, no_of_user_objects: 2}]
```

Comment: Number of queries will be huge.

Comment: because this data changes overtime and not static like in DB, i don't think there other ways to get these kind of data unless you write query expression to interact with the database itself. @RoyalBosS if you want to display in a list, having pagination won't causing much slow down

Comment: i just want count

Comment: @RoyalBosS that's what my model method do, it count() the number of user having the same id

Comment: yes but number of sql query increases with increasing number of objects

Comment: actually no, if you implement pagination to your view, it won't query all database. For example these docs https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/ , https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/pagination/. I used model method on all my projects with million of dataset and i see no slowness, because i implemented pagination. Mostly slow query are due to foreign key query which isn't what we doing, even with foreign key query you can make it faster with `select_related()`